# Is length of a hashmap costly operation?

Tags: data-structures, compiler-construction, time-complexity

Is finding the length of a hash map a costly operation? I understand it depends on the implementation, so how about in these languages

1. Javascript
2. Java
3. Python
4. PHP (in PHP we do `count(<Array>)` if I am correct)

### Additional Question

Is there any source where I can learn how to determine cost of an operation (starting from primitive data types to complex structures) ?

Comment: Just specifying language isn't enough information, since there may be more than one implementation in a language and more than one algorithm to get the size.  To determine the cost of operations, learn about complexity theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory

Answer (score 1):

**HashMap** in Java collection has the method **size()** to return its member **size** updated accordingly whenever there's a change in the elements.

If you are looking for its computational complexity,

the time-complexity of the method **size()** itself is clearly constant.

The complexity of doing it from scratch-- ignoring the availability of **size** count that is already there and implementing your own method, it would be the same as the complexity of accessing all elements of the **HashMap** and is **O(n)**.